# Slider issue - How to can i support image and video in php slider

Tags: php, css, wordpress, slider, advanced-custom-fields

Website: https://www.orphanboards.com

Issue: the last slider (4th) shows a white border on desktop version, so I am trying to remove it by converting the last slider to image.

[Image of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E3QJ.jpg)

How can I make the slider support image URL, which currently supports only video URL or any better solution to remove the white space large screen?

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_parent' => null);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
foreach ($attachments as $post) {?>

<div class="item">
    <video muted id="video01" poster="" class="video01" autoplay="" loop>
        <source src="<?php the_field('video_url', $post->ID); ?>" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/images/video01.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
    <div class="orphan_banner_content">
        <h2 class="vedio_hd"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'button_tilte', true) ) : ?>
        <a class="banner01_btn" href="<?php the_field('button_url', $post->ID); ?>">
            <?php the_field('button_tilte', $post->ID); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the full code with javascript as well.

Comment: @Bhautik then I need to share the entire website code, here is the website: https://www.orphanboards.com.

Comment: But I can see this is working fine.